# Cakephp3: Accessing View content inside Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am converting my existing website from `CakePHP 2.x` to `CakePHP 3.x`.

I have used following code in cakePHP2 to get view rendered content in controller. *(I know this is not recommendable way to do, but I somehow need it.)*

```
ob_start();
$view = new View($this, false);
$payment_form = $view->render();
ob_end_clean();
```

I have tried this **but not working**:

```
ob_start();
$view = new \Cake\View\View($this->request, $this->response);
$payment_form = $view->render('/Orders/index');
ob_end_clean();
```

I searched on web but couldn't get any help for similar CakePHP3 code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After googling and other trial/error, I have figured out way to do so.

```
$data = "This will be accessible in view if it will be set in view builder";

// create a builder (hint: new ViewBuilder() constructor works too)
$builder = $this->viewBuilder();

// configure as needed
$builder->autoLayout(false);
$builder->template('Orders/process_order');
$builder->helpers(['Html']);

// create a view instance (set variables here which you want to access in view)
$view = $builder->build(['data' => $data]);

// render to a variable
$payment_form = $view->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean`,   The `View` handles that part

```
$view = new \Cake\View\View($this->request, $this->response);
$payment_form = $view->render('/Orders/index'); //Returns the view content

//echo $payment_form;
```

Comment: This didn't work dear. As `ob_start/flush` doesn't make any difference here. Anyway thanks!